# Nlog for logging using NLog API into Application Insight & table storage

Tags: .net, nlog

I am trying out NLog for logging my logs to ApplicationInsights & Az table. Since I have many regions and I prefer not to keep the instrumentation key in config files I am writing a library project in .NET 4.7.1 using the below method.

```
 public void AddTelemetryTarget()
        {
            try
            {
                InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
                // enable internal logging to a file               
                InternalLogger.LogToConsoleError = true;
                // enable internal logging to a custom TextWriter
                TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"D:\My Files\PayloadLog.txt");
                InternalLogger.LogWriter = writer; //e.g. TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\perl.txt")
                // set internal log level
                InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Trace;

                LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
                var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
                //Registering Nlog target with application insight
                ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition("ApplicationInsightsTarget", typeof(ApplicationInsightsTarget));
                ApplicationInsightsTarget aiTarget = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();
                aiTarget.InstrumentationKey = "instrumentationKey";
                aiTarget.Name = "ai";

                var wrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper(aiTarget, 5000, AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow);
                config.AddTarget("TelemetryAsyncWrapper", wrapper);
                //Applying logging rules.
                LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", ConvertLogType(LogLevel.Info), aiTarget);
                config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

                LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory(config);
                NLog.Logger _logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

                LogEventInfo logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
                logEventInfo.Level = NLog.LogLevel.Info;
                logEventInfo.Properties.Add("ModuleName", "TestModule");
                logEventInfo.Properties.Add("MethodName", "TestMethod");
                _logger.Info(logEventInfo);

                logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo();
                logEventInfo.Level = NLog.LogLevel.Error;
                logEventInfo.Properties.Add("ModuleName", "ExceptioModule");
                logEventInfo.Properties.Add("MethodName", "ExceptionMethod");
                _logger.Error(logEventInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

But the logs are not found in Application Insights.

[image: Nuget Packages]

I have added the above Nuget packages. Am i missing something ?

There is no error in the internal logs too

Comment: You should use this nuget-package for writing to Table Storage: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureCosmosTable/ See also https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage#table-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping into some traps.

Never activate LogManager.ThrowExceptions for production code (Only use for troubleshoting):

```
LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
```

This constructor should never be used:

```
LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory(config);
NLog.Logger _logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Instead you should do this:

```
LogManager.Configuration = config;
NLog.Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

When writing a LogEvent then you should include a message:

```
var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, null, "My custom message");
logEventInfo.Properties["ModuleName"] = "TestModule";
logEventInfo.Properties["MethodName"] = "TestMethod";
_logger.Log(logEventInfo);
```

When using async writing, then you should remember to flush before app-exit:

```
LogManager.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Maybe also recommend WithProperty :)

Comment: enable exception i set for debugging. Will try out the comments and will revert back. Also can you give me more insight on why this should not be used
LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory(config);
NLog.Logger _logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
Thanks for it :)

Comment: Because LoggingConfiguration belongs to the LogFactory it was created for (Using default constructor for LoggingConfiguration means it belongs to the static LogManager.LogFactory) . Assigning a LoggingConfiguration to a different LogFactory can give unexpected results.